# how to compile two scss to two different css file

Tags: css, npm, sass, compilation, watch

I have two SCSS files that I want to make two css from each SCSS

I have this right now for one SCSS file:

```json
"watch:sass": "node-sass assets/stylesheets/custom.scss assets/stylesheets/custom.css -w",
"compile:sass": "node-sass assets/stylesheets/custom.scss assets/stylesheets/custom.comp.css",
```

How can add one more to this?

Answer (score 0):

May i know which editor  are you using??????
If you are using something like VSCode then there is an extension named LiveSASS compiler which watches and then automatically compiles your SASS files to css files.

Comment: can we do it by adding to package.jason file?

Comment: I also am a beginer so I really dont know. Sorry.